# How can I automate openssl in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, encryption, automation, openssl

I am using OpenSSL (from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) to decrypt a file retrieved from external sftp site. The external site is publishing new files daily, each with new filenames. At the moment when the file is downloaded I have to manually go into Openssl.exe and type the following each time

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe cms –decrypt –inkey C:\key.pem –recip C:\cert.pem –inform DER –in \\server01\filename.xml.crypt –out \\server01\Decrypt\filename.xml
```

I tried putting this in a batch file (*.bat) but when I ran that it did not work. The only thing that I have managed to get to work is the manual process described above.

Is there a way to automate this and avoid having to manually type the whole code above? I should mention the filename.xml.crypt is actually normally around 100 characters long...

Ideally looking at a windows batch file, or something similar?

Sorry if this is a stupid question!

TIA
Hamez

Comment: I don't see any reason that the code you posted wouldn't have worked (unless the paths have spaces and you didn't put quotes around them, of course). What error message did you get?

Comment: When I try running the above code from a batch file, I get the following:

"cms: Use -help for summary."

Comment: I also get the following error:

Invalid command 'cms ûdecrypt'

does this mean there something wrong with the '-'? Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the exact same issues. The hyphen '-' is being converted to the accented u (i.e. -recip, -inform etc). No doubt we've all copied it from a webpage and that has altered the code base of the hyphen. I've just manually inputted the - for all the command line parameters and now it's worked.